# Is there a word to describe a person who is so interested in the detail of everything? Especially a word with a positive meaning

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am wondering if there is a word to describe a person who is so enthusiastic about the details of a particular subject. I know the word geek. But I am wondering if there are more words to describe a person with the mentioned feature. The word must be a positive word, though could have a negative meaning as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if there is a word to describe a person who is so
> enthusiastic about the details of a particular subject

**maven** (n.)

> A maven is a person who is an expert on a particular subject.
> *[US]*
>
> *...the gossip columnists and fashion mavens of New York City.*  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/maven)

> One who is experienced or knowledgeable : EXPERT
>
> *a language maven*
> *policy mavens*
> *computer mavens* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maven)